# Warnings on HDD FAILURE

Tags: windows, windows-xp

My HDD is giving some failure warnings:

> smart failure predicted on hard disk 0: samsung HM321H-(PM), WARNING: immediately back-up your data and replace your hard disk drive: a failure may be imminent. Press f1 to continue

It's a new laptop, about 4-6 months old. Is it possible that the hard drive has really died this early? If not, what could be the problem?

It's running on phoenix vision.

Comment: Have a look at statistics, bathtub curve for failure rates.   Anything can fail at anytime, but statistically, they either fail early, or fail late.   You may have just won the 'fail early' prize. (bathtub curve... awesome name!)

Answer (score 1):

As the message says: **back up your data now**

If it is within warranty (and being 4-6 months from purchase, it should be) take it to a service center or the place of purchase.

It is possible for it to fail this young, but unlikely unless you have physically damaged the disk, which can be caused by high g-forces on the disk (dropping, kicking, stepping on). It is MUCH easier to damage while it is running.

Comment: Thankx 4 the help, the whole story jz strtd whn i made sme windws reinstallation , if i pres f1 it wil continue and i wl be able to use it, tryd runing dskchk bt found no error, can't be able to disable the error report?

Comment: @Fillipus: that doesn't mean the drive isn't failing.  Modern drives can keep going, hiding the errors from the operating system, despite having serious hardware problems ... right up to the point where they can't.

Comment: An early failure isn't really particularly unlikely.  Perhaps one chance in a few hundred for any particular drive.  An error message is more likely to be due to a real failure than to be a false alarm, and a manufacturing defect is just as plausible a cause as accidental damage.  (I don't know the actual stats, but based on my experience I'd guess that if anything, the odds favour the manufacturing defect.)

Comment: I have not seen a HDD fail early. And I have seen a lot of hard drives. That's why I made that statement.

Comment: You may be right.  I went back through my records and could only find one case, out of perhaps 400-odd new machines over the relevant time period.  (I thought I'd seen more than that, but apparently not.)